# Что не так в запросе (sql)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Мой sql запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM "photos" WHERE ("by" = "Login" AND "by" = "ilyaspark") ORDER BY "ID" DESC
```

Ошибка:

```
Invalid column name 'Login'.
```

Comment: А для чего названия таблицы и полей брать в кавычки?

Comment: Даже если предположить, что в запросе правильно расставлены кавычки выражение `"by" = "Login" AND "by" = "ilyaspark"` всегда будет эволюционировать в `false`. @IliaDementiev, что-то не то вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: попробуй нормально, как все:  where login = 'BY'

Comment: By, login, ilayspark – что здесь название поля, а что значение?

Comment: Структуру таблицы в студию! :)

Comment: Спасибо, ребят!)  Проблема была в том, что значения полей были в двойных кавычках. Я пробывал их и совсем убирать, но помогло только когда выставил ординарные, почему-то... 
@InterfaceUnknown by было название  полей)

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown, так приходится делать потому, что `by` - это название колонки, и одновременно ключевое слово. Без экранирования ключевые слова нельзя использовать для указания имен таблиц/колонок.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov понятно, спасибо! У нас при помощи квадратных скобок.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown, в SQL то стандартно как-раз двойными кавычками - в том числе в Microsoft SQL Server. Скобки - это из режима совместимости с Microsoft Access.

А MySQL немного другая история - они SQL поддерживать не собираются впринципе. Совсем, не смотря наличие 'SQL' в их названии. Грубо говоря, у них "свой собственный язык запросов, внешне сильно напоминаюший SQL". По этой причине, перенос проектов с/на MySQL практически невозможен без переписывания большей части запросов.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown, справедливости стоит сказать, что конкретно двойные кавычки там включаются, однако для этого нужно править конфигурацию сервера, что не всегда допустимо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Названия полей и таблиц в MySQL обычно экранируют обратным апострофом( `̀` - символ над клавищей `Ё` на клавиатуре), а вовсе не двойными кавычками.

Соответственно ваш запрос должен был выглядить так:

```
SELECT * FROM `photos` WHERE (`by` = "Login" AND `by` = "ilyaspark") ORDER BY `ID` DESC
```

Двойные кавычки можно использовать только если в конфигурации сервера MySQL установлена опция `ANSI_QUOTES`, что у хостеров встречается крайне редко. Обычный же апостраф для экранирования работает всегда, и поэтому лучше использовать именно его.

Comment: Почему то ординарные кавычки ( ' ) прошли с названием полей,
а двойные кавычки в названии таблицы ставит сам codeigniter при запросе $this->db->get('photos')

Comment: Век живи - век учись. у нас в SQL Server как-то все попроще ;)

Comment: Апострофы (это именно апострофы а не одинарные кавычки), не обязательны в MySQL за исключением случаев, когда идентификатор совпадает с зарезервированным словом. (Кстати есть два списка зарезервированных слов: один содержит слова, которые могут быть использованы при заключении в апострофы, а другой -- слова которые вообще не могут быть использованы.)