# Что не так в sql запросе 2

Tags: sql

У меня есть база данных `photos`, и в ней колонка `"by"`. Есть множество строк в таблице, где значение `by` равно `test1` , и других, где значение `by` равно `test2`. Как выбрать все строки, в которых значение `by` равно `test1` или `test2`?

Вот мой запрос:

```
SELECT "photo_link" FROM "photos" WHERE "by" = 'test1' AND "by" = 'test2'
```

Ошибок sql нет, но возвращается пустой массив.

Я пробовал менять `and` на `or`, но никакого толка:

```
SELECT "photo_link" FROM "photos" WHERE "by" = 'test1' OR "by" = 'test2'
```

Comment: Ответы на предыдущий ваш вопрос ушли в пустоту.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что не так в запросе (sql)?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444001/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-sql)

Comment: @Visman проблема из предыдущего запроса решилась, вообще-то.. читайте вопросы внимательней..

Comment: Вам нужен именно `OR`, `AND` в данном случае бессмысленно рассматривать. Если `OR` не работает, значит проблема в чем-то другом (кавычки, ваша ORM или что-то еще)!

Comment: @IliaDementiev: проблема, возможно, решилась, но вы снова названия полей заключаете в двойные кавычки.

Answer (score 2):

Ваша проблема кроется в условии запроса:

```
WHERE "by" = 'test1' AND "by" = 'test2'
```

Одно и то же поле (`by`) не может быть *одновременно* равно и `test1` и `test2`. По всей видимости, вы имели в виду вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT photo_link FROM photos WHERE `by` = 'test1' OR `by` = 'test2'
```

**UPD:**

И, да, название полей **нельзя** заключать в двойные кавычки (см. [Что не так в запросе (sql)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444001/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5-sql))

**UPD2:**

Настоятельно рекомендую переименовать поле `by` во что-то, что не является ключевым словом.

Comment: А возможно как то получить одним запросом все строки, где by = test1 или test2?
(менять and на or я пробовал)

Comment: Вообще-то `OR` делает именно то, что вам нужно. Если нет, то разберитесь, для начала, с кавычками вокруг названий полей.

Comment: Дело в том,что не сам я заключаю это в кавычки, это делает codeigniter с помощью active records: 
$this->db->where('by', $value->user_id);

Comment: А вы сам запрос выполнять пробовали? Может проблема не в запросе, а в CodeIgniter (его конфигурации)?