# Не работает запись в базу данных из php(SQL запрос ошибок не выдавал)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте, есть две переменные(логин и пароль) которые передает `ajax` в `php` методом `POST`'. Далее мне нужно из БД достать всё, что там есть и узнать занят ли уже такое имя. Пытаюсь сделать это так но ничего не происходит. Почему так?`SQL`в `phpmyadmin` ошибок не выбивал.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'myDb');

if( $connection == false)
{
    echo 'Не удалось подключиться к базе данных!<br>';
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
session_start();
$name     = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$_SESSION['user'] = $name;
$_SESSION['pass'] = $password;

if (!isset($name, $password) || empty($name) || empty($password)){
    http_response_code(400);
    die();
}

$count = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE(`Name` == '$name' AND `Password` = '$password') ");

if (mysqli_num_rows($count) == 0)
{
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`Name`, `Password`) VALUES ('$name', '$password')");
}
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: кавычки не те в `'Name'`. замените на апострофы. плюс оберните кавычками саму переменную `'$name'`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что не так в запросе (sql)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444001/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-sql)

Comment: Замените `Name` == '$name' => `Name` = '$name'

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю проблема в передаче переменный в SQL команду.
Вот так попробуйте:

```
$count = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE(`Name` = '" . $name . "' AND `Password` = '" . $password . "') ");

if (mysqli_num_rows($count) == 0)
{
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`Name`, `Password`) VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $password . "')");
}
```

Также обратите внимание, что если `$name` или `$password` будет содержать апостроф (`'`), то SQL не сработает.

Comment: Записи в таблицу всёравно нет.

Comment: С учетом моих изменений я не вижу ошибок в коде. А значит ошибка либо в данных, либо в таблице. Проверьте именя полей; их регистр в коде и в БД; убедитесь, что `$name` и `$password` не пустые. Попробуйте вывести на экран оба SQL (и SELECT, и INSERT)...

Comment: Включите вывод ошибок: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` - может быть так система сама покажет, в чем дело.

Comment: У меня происходит так что значения в переменных `$name` и `$password` присваиваются им из  формы только после нажатия на кнопку. Из за этого могут быть проблемы?

Comment: ну я так понимаю, что при нажатии на кнопку посылается `ajax` запрос в этот код... Так? Если "да", то так и должно быть.... Нажатие на кнопку делает `POST` в этот код, и поля `user` и `pass` должны содержать то, что пользователь ввел в поле формы.

Comment: да, все верно, тогда я вообще не понимаю почему не работает. Запрос `AJAX` происходит успешно.

Comment: Поставьте вот это `die("INSERT INTO users (Name, Password) VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $password . "')");` перед строкой `$count = `. Что видите?

Comment: Все работает, простите меня, дурака, за то что я забыл в `mysqli_query` написать `$connection`))

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqli_query($connection, 'INSERT INTO `users` (`Name`, `Password`) VALUES ("' . $name . '", "' . $password . '")');
```

Попробуйте вот так