# Авторизация пользователя на php, сравнение данных из БД

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть форма, пользователь вводит в нее имя и пароль, скрипт проверят есть ли уже такое имя в БД, если нет-то записывает пару в таблицу. Если такое имя есть то проверяет подходит ли введенные имя и пароль. Подскажите пожалуйста, я никак не могу реализовать проверку соответствия имени и пароля.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'omnikross', 'easy_chat');

if( $connection == false)
{
    echo 'Не удалось подключиться к базе данных!<br>';
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

session_start();
$name     = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$_SESSION['user'] = $name;
$_SESSION['pass'] = $password;
$count = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `Name` FROM  `users` WHERE(`Name` = '$name')");

if (mysqli_num_rows($count) == 0)
{
    mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `users` (`Name`, `Password`) VALUES ('$name', '$password')");
} 
else if ( mysqli_num_rows (mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE(`Name` = '$name', AND `Password` = '$password'") ) == 0) 
{
    http_response_code(400);
    die();
}
```

Comment: _никогда_ не подставляйте значения переменных непосредственно в текст запроса. В вашем случае появление кавычек в имени пользователя или пароле приведет к синтаксической ошибке запроса во время выполнения в лучшем случае и к взлому вашего сервера в худшем (50% всех взломов происходят именно по таким причинам). _Всегда_ используйте привязку значений переменных http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @Mike Хорошо, не буду, но конкретно сейчас проблема в том что это не имеет смысле т.к. код не работает..

Comment: А что у вас в части `WHERE(Name = '$name', AND Password = '$password'")` делает запятая ?

Comment: случайно нажал, без нее тоже не работает так, как нужно. Оно выбивает ошибку когда даже пароль подходит.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает запись в базу данных из php(SQL запрос ошибок не выдавал)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/721907/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-phpsql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb)

Answer (score 1):

У вас серьезные ошибки с синтаксисом и печатанием букв. Либо поменяйте клавиатуру, либо очки - в коде нельзя делать такие ошибки

1. Запятая, уже сказали
2. Кавычка, закрывающая строку SQL, стоит не там
3. Обязательно [используйте escape string](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) в запросе, даже в учебном и тестовом коде

```html
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'omnikross', 'easy_chat');

if( $connection == false)
{
    echo 'Не удалось подключиться к базе данных!<br>';
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

session_start();
$name     = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$_SESSION['user'] = $name;
$_SESSION['pass'] = $password;
$count = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `Name` FROM  `users` WHERE `Name` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string(connection, $name)."'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($count) == 0)
{
    mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `users` (`Name`, `Password`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string(connection, $name)."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string(connection, $password)."')");
}
else if ( mysqli_num_rows (mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE `Name` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string(connection, $name)."' AND `Password` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string(connection, $password)."'" ) == 0) 
{
    http_response_code(400);
    die();
}

?>
```

Теперь, после исправления всех базовых ошибок, должно все работать

Последнее, что надо сделать обязательно - хранить не пароли, а хеши паролей, хотя бы md5 с солью, или через MySQL [PASSWORD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-hashing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Конечно можешь. Расширь запрос, который ты формируешь. В итоге получится что-то вроде

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Name` = '$name' AND `Password` = '$password'
```

Но я бы не хранил пароль в чистом виде ни в базе данных ни в сессии пользователя. Уж слишком это небезопасно. Погугли на тему сравнения хеш-сум паролей

Comment: Не совсем понимаю о чем вы, мой запрос вроде так и выглядит.